# Setting a Custom Key When Pushing New Data to Firebase Database through using the firebase-arduino Library

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, arduino-ide

Here I am adding new JSON data into my firebase database. However, the data generates a new unique key for the data. I would like to remove that unique key or make it custom. Whichever is easier.

```
  const size_t capacity = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 30;
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(capacity);
  const char* json = "{\"todayTimestamp\":[42,18]}";
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
  Firebase.push("Dates/",root);
```

"todayTimestamp2" is an example of how I need the JSON data to be added.
[image]

Here is the documentation for the library if this helps:
https://firebase-arduino.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Calling push() will generate a key for you.

If instead you use child(), you can determine the key/path yourself.

```
ref.child("someID").set("setting custom key when pushing new data to firebase database");
```

On the Arduino you're out of luck: [This open issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/377) ftom 2018 was not even answered by the developers. There are 136 open issues some more than 2 years, not a good signof active development imho,

Comment: I don’t think this works for the arduino-Firebase library I’m using in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: OOF, thanks anyway. I guess I'll make use of what the documentation gives me.